# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' : return code '0x1' Stop. in command prompt

Tags: cmd, nmake

I've been following a guido to compile a library into MATLAB. I've installer visualstudio14 so that i have a C++ compiler, then i used the `vsvarsxx.bat` to use the vs14 compiler with the cmd. For last, i went to the folder i want to compile and tiped nmake `nmake -f Makefile.win clean all`.

I used a following commands:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
vsvars32.bat
cd C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\estágio\PRoNTo_v2.0\PRoNTo_v2.0\machines\libsvm-3.20
nmake -f Makefile.win clean all
```

It runs whithout problem until i reach the final command. It pops up the following error:

> erase /Q *.obj windows. Could Not Find
>   C:\Users\Rafa\Desktop\estágio\PRoNTo_v2.0\PRoNTo_v2.0\machines\libsvm-3.20*.obj
>   cl.exe /nologo /O2 /EHsc /I. /D _WIN32 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -c
>   svm.cpp 'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' :
>   return code '0x1' Stop.

I have a Makefile.win: 03/25/2016 09:25 PM 732 Makefile 03/25/2016 09:25 PM 1,084 Makefile.win

I dont understand why that error pops up. Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check your %PATH% variable right before that point?

I'm thinking it may be overflowing, but that's just a theory.